# Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259 how to resolve this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've tried to find some information about this error but with no significant results. I try to send an email with Excel file as an attachment but I receive this error:

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Here's my code:

```
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name= 'SQLProfile',
    @recipients='myemail@xxx.pl',
    @subject='HLR 1000 - CC Lista', 
    @body='Proteza - do przeksztalcenia z csv > excel',
    @query =' print ''sep=;''; SELECT * from analizy.dbo.csv', 
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'CSV_Extract.csv',
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @query_result_separator = ';',
    @query_no_truncate = 1
```

Comment: check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/104156

Comment: Database Mail Profile that is used for the SQL server agent need to be a member of DatabaseMailUserRole in the msdb database.